# What do Salamanders eat?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, planes, food-and-drink

In the D&D 5e *Monster Manual*, most elementals state explicitly that they do not require food or drink. This is not the case for [salamanders](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/salamander). By omission, they need to eat and drink. The [Forgotten Realms wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Salamander) claims salamanders are omnivorous, although it is unclear what source this line is attributed to. I note that genies also need to eat by a similar omission.

They need to eat and drink, but *what* do they eat and drink? They are native to the Elemental Plane of Fire and are elementals, which implies a rather alien physiology and and ecosystem, but they also look creature-like and have something vaguely resembling a natural lifecycle, which implies that some behaviours might be familiar. Also unlike the elementals which do not need to eat, salamanders are as susceptible to poison as any other creature, further implying something resembling a physiology.

While I am running fifth edition, I'll take lore from any official material from any edition. If there isn't direct information about what salamanders eat, information about what on the Plane of Fire might be edible is also useful (but information about salamanders is preferable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Nothing

*Dragon 314* tells us in a pop-out text highlight: "A salamander has no drive to obtain sustenance..."

While 2nd Edition's *Monstrous Manual* confirms an omnivorous diet, it doesn't specify anything in the ecology section regarding obligation to eat. Salamanders obtain such nutrition as they require from smoke and flames. They can **choose** to eat for pleasure (and likely will do so, being creatures of fire) but are under no obligation. It should be noted that the Elemental Plane of Fire does have local flora and fauna such as the teleporting ratlike scape, various types of insect, and the lizardlike waiveras, which often feeds on fire snake eggs (*Planescape Monstrous Compendium Appendix III*).